# Passing a parameter to a regular expression to match the first letter in a word in perl

Tags: regex, perl

So here is what I'm doing. This is for homework, and I know I can't come on here and get you guys to do my homework for me but I'm stuck. We have to use perl (First time ever using it so forgive my stupidity) to make a function $starts_with that takes a parameter $str0 and $prefix. if $str0 starts with $prefix. then the function returns true. if it doesn't then it isn't pretty simple. We have to use regular expressions because that is the whole point of the exercise so here is my code

```
sub starts_with
{
    $str0 = $_[0];
    $prefix = $_[1];

    if($prefix =~ /^($str0)/)
    {
        print $str0."\n";
        print m/^(prefix)/."\n";
        $startsWith = "Y"
    }

    if ($startsWith eq "Y")
    {
        print $str0." starts with ".$prefix."\n";
    }
    else
    {
        print $str0." does not start with ".$prefix."\n";
    }

}
```

I'm almost ashamed to put this up here because I have no Idea what I'm doing yet. But I am trying to learn. I don't know how to do true false in perl thats why I have the $startsWith variable. you can fix that if you want. the part I need to fix is the line

```
if(str0 =~ /^($prefix)/)
```

I also need to find out how to refer to the first letter in str0...I think

Comment: Does it return False if the string does not start with the prefix?

Answer (score 3):

A couple points without giving away the answer:

1) Arguments to functions are passed in a special variable called `@_`, which is what you are accessing when you say `$_[0]` and `$_[1]`, but can be written much more concisely by assigned the argument list (`@_`) to your variables in [*list context*](http://blogs.perl.org/users/nate_glenn/2014/01/list-assignment-in-scalar-context.html)

```
sub starts_with {
   my ($str0, $prefix) = @_;
   ...
}
```

2) This statement: `if($prefix =~ /^($str0)/)` tests the exact opposite condition you are trying to prove. It says does the prefix start with the value of the variable `$str0`. What you really want to test is if `$str0` starts with `$prefix`.

It might also be using to prefix your pattern with m flag, `m/PATTERN` which means *match* this pattern.

3) You don't have a return statement in your function, (As @M42 points out) the result of the last expression is returned; that expression being `print` will return true. You probably want to return true or false explicity.

See if you can use this to get started.

Comment: Nice to see someone actually **explaining** instead of pasting ready to go code.

Comment: I disagree with the point 3. It returns the result of the last  statement (ie.: print), certainly a true value.

Answer (score 1):

What I would do :

```
use Modern::Perl; # or use strict; use warnings; use feature qw/say/;

sub starts_with {
    # better use @_, the default array instead of just elements of them
    # ...like $_[0]
    my ($str, $pref) = @_;

    # very short expression, the pattern matching return a boolean.
    # \Q\E is there to treat the prefix as-is (no metacharacters)
    return $str =~ /^\Q$pref\E/;
}

# using our function
if (starts_with("foobar", "f")) {
    say "TRUE";
}
else {
    say "FALSE";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Golfing it a bit...

```
sub starts_with { $_[0] =~ /^\Q$_[1]/ }
```

Don't hand that version in though :-)